# App unable to obtain microphone access

Tags: windows-10, microphone

I have been Unable to get a UC application to detect microphone and camera on a Windows 10 machine. I'm hoping to find anyone here who may have experienced something similar before that is able to give some directions to this matter before I resort to a reformat of the machine.

UC application in question is Zulu Desktop. I have deployed this application on multiple windows 10 machine but none have experienced this issue. On the affected machine, there are no issues microphone issues with other applications like Zoom, Teams, or browser app UC on Chrome, edge or FireFox. When working correctly, the application would have appeared under windows 10 microphone privacy settings "Allow desktop apps to access your microphone". But it does not for this machine.

Troubleshooting steps taken:

1. Uninstall ZuluDesktop
2. Uninstall Webcam & Microphone Drivers
3. Reboot Machine
4. Install Microphone & Webcam Drivers
5. Reboot Machine
6. Install ZuluDesktop
7. Verified UC Applications like Teams & Zoom have no problems with Microphone settings. ZuluDesktop Still unable to grab microphone.

Comment: What exactly is a "UC application"?